# How to add a new line into a txt file using PHP

Tags: php, text-files

I wrote a function to insert some text into a txt file (using a foreach), but I'd like to go in a new line for each element. Any suggestiong?

This is my function:

```
function process_page($page) {
    $html = get_html($page);

    foreach($html->find("h1") as $div) {

        $show = $div;
        $show = strip_tags($show);

        $data = '\n' . $show;
        $ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

        if($ret === false) {
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        }
        else {
            echo "$ret bytes written to file";
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to insert `'\n'` but it write it into text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `'\n'` with `"\n"`. The escape sequence is not recognized when you use `'`.

**See the [manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)**

Comment: I believe depending on the OS used it could differ. In case of Windows it could also be \r or \r\n.

Comment: Or of course as Nigel Ren suggested using PHP_EOL.

Comment: It's working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that it's platform independant - use `PHP_EOL`, this ensures it's the right encoding for the platform your currently running on.

```
$data = PHP_EOL . $show;
```